# Null object when setting the value

Tags: java, android

I make a request, get a list and make a weather forecast out of it. On request, it comes to a variable, but when setting the value, I get an error. Help find the problem.

The problem is in the line -   `String tempWithDegree = weatherDays.get(position).getTempWithDegree(); holder.textViewTemp.setText(tempWithDegree);`

Debug shows that the variable gets value

Class WeatherDay:

```
public class WeatherDay {

public  class WeatherTemp {
    Double temp;
    Double temp_min;
    Double temp_max;
}

public  class WeatherDescription {
    String icon;
}

@SerializedName("main")
private WeatherTemp temp;

@SerializedName("weather")
private List<WeatherDescription> descriptions;

@SerializedName("name")
private String city;

@SerializedName("dt")
private long timestamp;

public WeatherDay(WeatherTemp temp, List<WeatherDescription> descriptions) {
    this.temp = temp;
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
}

public Calendar getDate() {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000);
    return date;
}

public String getTemp() { return String.valueOf(temp.temp); }

public String getTempMin() { return String.valueOf(temp.temp_min); }

public String getTempMax() { return String.valueOf(temp.temp_max); }

public String getTempInteger() { return String.valueOf(temp.temp.intValue()); }

public String getTempWithDegree() { return (temp.temp.intValue()) + "\u00B0"; }

public String getCity() { return city; }

public String getIcon() { return descriptions.get(0).icon; }

public String getIconUrl() {
    return "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + descriptions.get(0).icon + ".png";
}
```

Class Forecast:

```
  @SerializedName("list")
private List<WeatherDay> items;

public WeatherForecast(List<WeatherDay> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public List<WeatherDay> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

My Adapter Class:

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ForecastHolder>{
private List<WeatherDay> weatherDays = new ArrayList<>();



@NonNull
@Override
public ForecastHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_item, parent, false);
    return new ForecastHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ForecastHolder holder, int position) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatDayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
    if (weatherDays.get(position).getDate().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 15) {
        String dayOfWeek = formatDayOfWeek.format(weatherDays.get(position).getDate().getTime());
        holder.textViewDay.setText(dayOfWeek);

    //    String tempWithDegree = weatherDays.get(position).getTempWithDegree();
   //     holder.textViewTemp.setText(tempWithDegree);
        Picasso.get().load(weatherDays.get(position).getIconUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return weatherDays.size();
}

public void setWeatherDays(List<WeatherDay> days) {
    weatherDays.addAll(days);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearForecasts() {
    weatherDays.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class ForecastHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewTemp;
    private TextView textViewDay;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ForecastHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTemp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTemp);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewDay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDay);
    }
}
```

}

Thank for u help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception was thrown because textViewTemp is null in `holder.textViewTemp.setText(...)`.

You are not setting a value for `textViewTemp` in the view holder object in the `onCreateViewHolder` method. If it looks like you are, consider the possibility that looking up the view failed. Perhaps the layout you are using does not have a view with the ID you are using.

Comment: OMG, i'm find my mistake. Thank for hint.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't about value. It's about `textViewTemp`. You haven't initialized it. If you share your adapter class, we can help you